# React not showing updated state in child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This is an adaptation of the [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).
My intent is to use the selection of one or two players to migrate towards an automatic 
selection of moves.  At this stage for some reason the selection of squares is not being 
captured in the call to `handleMove(i)` with the  `this.setState({squares:this.state.squares, xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext})` statement, as can be seen from the 
two console.log calls in both the Button and Square components.

This is the technique employed in the tutorial so I am not sure why the squares array is not
updating.  I read other postings and Facebook's discussion of immutability that states 
the function (in this case the `handleMove(i)`, correct?) must complete before the change to state
is reflected in the overall state.  The calls to console.log in the other componets as well as the overall DOM
do not reflect the clicks on the squares.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?  Thank you.

On [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pebutaw/1/edit?html,js)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='root'></div>
<script type='text/babel' >


function Square(props){
  console.log(props.value);
  return(
    <button className="square" onClick={() => props.onClick()}>{props.value}</button>    
    );
}



class Board extends React.Component{
  renderSquare(i){
    console.log(this.props.squares);  
    return <Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)} />
  }  

  render(){
    return(
    <div className="board">
    <div className="row">
        {this.renderSquare(0)}
        {this.renderSquare(1)}
        {this.renderSquare(2)}
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        {this.renderSquare(3)}
        {this.renderSquare(4)}
        {this.renderSquare(5)}
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        {this.renderSquare(6)}
        {this.renderSquare(7)}
        {this.renderSquare(8)}
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}


class Game extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      onePlayerGame: true,
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true
    }
  }

  onePlayer(){
    this.setState({onePlayerGame: true});
    return(
    document.getElementById('onePlayer').style.color = "yellow",
    document.getElementById('twoPlayer').style.color = "black"
    );
  }


  twoPlayer(){
    this.setState({ onePlayerGame: false});
    return(
    document.getElementById('onePlayer').style.color= "black",
    document.getElementById('twoPlayer').style.color= "yellow"
    );

  }

  handleMove(i){
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X':'O';


    this.setState({
      squares: this.state.squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    })
  }



  render(){
    return(
    <div id="main">
      <div>
       <button className="gameSelect" id="onePlayer" value={this.state.onePlayerGame} onClick={() => this.onePlayer()}  >One Player</button>
       <button className="gameSelect"  id="twoPlayer"value={this.state.onePlayerGame} onClick={() => this.twoPlayer()}  >Two Players</button>
      </div>

      <Board 
        squares={this.state.squares} 
        onClick={(i) => this.handleMove(i)} />

    </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection is captured, but you are not saving the new value of `squares` in the `state`.

this

```
handleMove(i){
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X':'O';


    this.setState({
      squares: this.state.squares, <----- You are not assigning the new value
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    })
}
```

should be

```
handleMove(i){
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X':'O';


    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    })
}
```

Here is the proper [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/joludodame/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.